# How Microsoft Graph API OnlineMeeting authenticates Attendee

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created online meeting using [Microsoft-Graph-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and able to add attendee using below code:

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphAuthProvider();
                //meetingAttendees     
                MeetingParticipants meetingParticipants = new MeetingParticipants();

                List<MeetingParticipantInfo> meetingParticipantInfos = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>() { };
                meetingParticipants.Attendees = meetingParticipantInfos;               
               
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in drAttendee)
                {                    
                    meetingParticipantInfos.Add(new MeetingParticipantInfo { Upn = dataRow["Email"].NullToString() });
                }

                var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dr["StartDateTime"].NullToString()),
                    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dr["EndDateTime"].NullToString()),
                    Subject = dr["TrainingName"].NullToString(),                                                               
                    Participants = meetingParticipants

                };

                NewlyCreatedMeeting = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

My question is how Ms-Graph-API authenticates the attendee while joining actual meeting started by the organizer.It only ask for guest name as shown in the img:
[image]
For Eg:if attendee added while creating online meeting is with email id="abc@xyz.com".As shown in the img while joining he enters "abcxyz" or anything as name instead of emailid.How he can be authenticated as same attendee and not the anonymous user.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attendees` property in Microsoft Graph has no substantial use for the time being. I believe this property is still in change.

Even if you set attendees, they are the same as other users in the organization and can join into this meeting.

The difference between attendees and anonymous users is that if you set the [lobbyBypassScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/lobbybypasssettings?view=graph-rest-beta#lobbybypassscope-values) attribute, you can distinguish the way they enter the meeting. (Currently this attribute is only applicable to the beta version)

So if you set `lobbyBypassScope` to `organization`, attendees (and other users in the organization) can directly enter the meeting, bypassing the lobby. But anonymous users will need to be admit.

The login behavior of attendees is as follows: when you have logged in to the attendees account, you will display a login interface that is different from anonymous users. If you are not logged in to the attendees account, you can first enter an anonymous name and then click **sign in** to log in to the account. The meeting will recognize your attendees, not an anonymous user.

[image]

You can use what I said above to determine whether this user has joined this meeting as an anonymous user or not.

Comment: Allen:Thanx for your detail comment.I will check above and try to meet our requirement.

Comment: is there any settings in lobby `lobbyBypassScope`  to by pass only invited attendee instead of all organization people.It not always necessary that attendee will be in the organization.Attendee will be invited by using their emailids and ppl owned those emailids can bypass the lobby.Requirement is this.hope u understand now.

Comment: @anu Unfortunately this requirement is not supported currently.

Comment: @anu NP:) if my answer is helpful, you can mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Will surely mark it as an answer but till now my requirement is not satisfied.Once done will do it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anu Thank you. But not every requirement can be satisfied. I can only list the things that Microsoft graph can do for you currently. I appreciate your understanding:)

Comment: :thanx i am accepting as an ans as per you `not every requirement can be satisfied`